# Local or remote execution of powershell script with generic parameters

Tags: powershell, remote-access, invoke-command, splat

In a development team, I would like to have the same test scripts to be executed locally by a developper or remotely by our test platform.

Here is what I would like to use as premises for each script

```
# Test local/remote execution by reading C:\ directory
param(
    [switch] $verbose,
    [switch] $remote,
    [string] $ip,
    [string] $user,
    [string] $password
    #Add here script specific parameters
)

Write-Host "Command invokation incoming parameter count : " $psboundparameters.count

if ($remote) {
    $Params = @{}
    $RemoteParams = @{}
    $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force 

    $Params.Credential = new-object -TypeName System.management.automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user, $pass
    $Params.ComputerName = $ip
    $Params.FilePath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
    $null = $psboundparameters.Remove('remote')
    $null = $psboundparameters.Remove('ip')
    $null = $psboundparameters.Remove('user')
    $null = $psboundparameters.Remove('password')

    foreach($psbp in $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator())
    {
        $RemoteParams.$($psbp.Key)=$psbp.Value
    }
    Write-Host $RemoteParams
    Invoke-Command @Params @Using:RemoteParams
    Exit 
}

Write-Host "Command execution incoming parameters count : "    $psboundparameters.count

# Here goes the test 
Get-ChildItem C:\
```

However, when I execute this, I got the following error:

```
Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
```

It seems that **@Using:RemoteParams** is not the correct way of doing this, but I'm quite lost here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on the problem of being able to do both local and remote execution using named parameters:

```
$IP = '192.168.0.1'
$User = 'Test User'
$Password = 'P@ssW0rd!' 

$params = @{
IP = $IP
User = $User
Password = $Password
}

$command = 'new-something'

$ScriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create("$command $(&{$args} @Params)")
```

Start with a hash table of parameters, using local varibles, then use this:

```
[Scriptblock]::Create("$command $(&{$args} @Params)")
```

to create a script block of the command, with the parameters inline and the values already expanded.  Now that script block is ready to be run locally (either by invocation with `&` or dot-sourcing), or remotely using `Invoke-Command`.

```
$ScriptBlock
new-something -IP: 192.168.0.1 -User: Test User -Password: P@ssW0rd!
```

No scoping with `$Using:` or `-argumentlist` required.

Edit: Here's an example using a script rather than a single command:

```
$path = 'c:\windows'
$filter = '*.xml'

$Params = 
@{
   Path = $path
   Filter = $filter
  }

$command = @'
{
  Param (
    [String]$path,
    [String]$Filter
   )

 Get-childitem -Path $path -Filter $filter
}
'@

$ScriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create(".$command $(&{$args} @Params)")
```

To run it locally:

```
 Invoke-Command $ScriptBlock
```

or just:

```
 .$ScriptBlock
```

To run it remotely:

```
 Invoke-Command -Scriptblock $ScriptBlock -ComputerName Server1
```

Comment: The idea behind this scriptlet  is to use it at the beginning of each test script, so that users don't have to write a scriptblock that repeat the script parameters. I would like it to be as generic as possible, with the real parameter list declared only once in the named parameters block. For instance, the next step will be to discover "file type" parameters and prepare them in the script block.

Comment: If I'm understanding the comment correctly, you're concerned that the user script is embedded in the example as $command.  You can populate that just as easily by doing a Get-Content on the script file, and using the path to the script as a parameter. You can't use $using in the splat they way you've attempted.  It has to be specified on each variable reference within the the script, but if you do that then the script doesn't work locally.  This gives you a script block that will work locally or remotely without having to manipulate variable scopes in the script.